# Error at checkout page; "ConfigProvider does not exist"

Tags: magento2, module, error, onepage-checkout, plugin

I'm new around and trying to update existing module. I didn't make many changes on working module, but just added 2 files (models), and 5 lines of code to write database extra fields. New functionality works OK. However I realized that I some how broke checkout page, It's not working.

It says my plugin's ConfingProvider file doesn't exist but it is. Only change on this file is code formatting(indents etc.). I tried to override old working file, but it still doesn't work.

I'm using latest version of devbox, and docker.

I interestingly get this error with current formatted file(nothing else)

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class ' Ebizcharge\Ebizcharge\Model\ConfigProvider ' not found in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93
( ! ) Error: Class ' Ebizcharge\Ebizcharge\Model\ConfigProvider ' not found in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93
```

And this when using original working file;

```
2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class 
                    Myplugin\Myplugin\Model\ConfigProvider
                 does not exist

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage
#0 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(237): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->getBlockInstance('Magento\\Checkou...', Array)
#1 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(215): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->createBlock('Magento\\Checkou...', 'checkout.root', Array)
#2 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->generateBlock(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ScheduledStructure), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'checkout.root')
#3 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#4 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#5 /var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#6 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#7 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#9 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(197): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#10 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(217): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build()
#11 /var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Page/Config/Interceptor.php(50): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->getTitle()
#12 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Index/Index.php(39): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Interceptor->getTitle()
#13 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index->execute()
#14 /var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('execute', Array, Array)
#15 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#16 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage.php(161): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#19 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Checkou...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'contextPlugin')
#20 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/Context.php(106): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\Context->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Checkou...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'customer-app-ac...')
#23 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(61): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Checkou...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCheck')
#26 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/StoreCheck.php(44): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Checkou...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'weee-app-action...')
#29 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-weee/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(112): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Weee\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Checkou...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'tax-app-action-...')
#32 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(91): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Tax\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#35 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#36 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#38 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#39 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#40 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#41 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#42 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#43 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#44 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#45 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#46 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#47 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#48 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#49 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#50 /var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#51 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#52 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#53 /var/www/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#54 {main}

Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class 
                    Myplugin\Myplugin\Model\ConfigProvider
                 does not exist
#0 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('\n              ...')
#1 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('\n              ...')
#2 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('\n              ...')
#3 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('\n              ...')
#4 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(163): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('\n              ...')
#5 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(139): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->parseArray(Array)
#6 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, NULL, NULL, 'configProviders', 'Magento\\Checkou...')
#7 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Checkou...', Array, Array)
#8 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Checkou...')
#9 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(126): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Checkou...')
#10 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Checkou...', NULL, 'configProvider', 'Magento\\Checkou...')
#11 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Checkou...', Array, Array)
#12 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Checkou...', Array)
#13 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/BlockFactory.php(45): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Checkou...', Array)
#14 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(257): Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory->createBlock('Magento\\Checkou...', Array)
#15 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(237): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->getBlockInstance('Magento\\Checkou...', Array)
#16 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(215): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->createBlock('Magento\\Checkou...', 'checkout.root', Array)
#17 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->generateBlock(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ScheduledStructure), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'checkout.root')
#18 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#19 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#20 /var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#21 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#22 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#23 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#24 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(197): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#25 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(217): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build()
#26 /var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Page/Config/Interceptor.php(50): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->getTitle()
#27 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Index/Index.php(39): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Interceptor->getTitle()
#28 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index->execute()
#29 /var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('execute', Array, Array)
#30 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#31 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage.php(161): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#34 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Checkou...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'contextPlugin')
#35 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/Context.php(106): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#36 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\Context->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Checkou...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'customer-app-ac...')
#38 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(61): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#40 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Checkou...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCheck')
#41 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/StoreCheck.php(44): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#42 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#43 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Checkou...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'weee-app-action...')
#44 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-weee/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(112): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#45 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Weee\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#46 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Checkou...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'tax-app-action-...')
#47 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(91): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#48 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Tax\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#49 /var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#50 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#51 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#52 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#53 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#54 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#55 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#56 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#57 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#58 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#59 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#60 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#61 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#62 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#63 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#64 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#65 /var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#66 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#67 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#68 /var/www/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#69 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was a XML parsing problem. I restarted project, when PHP Storm formats XML's, it puts newlines etc, and looks like magento doesn't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Login via Ssh and go to the magento root directory delete var/generation or you can do it via ftp I recommend ssh

```
rm -rf var/generation
```

This should resolve your issue

Make sure you don't put a / before var

Comment: Run static content deploy to refresh all your generate code if that does not fix that error please paste code here so can review